# Can someone explain this code with structs please? (trying to learn Winsock 2)

Tags: c++, struct

I have typically seen structs of the form

```
struct Employee {
int age;
char* name;
}
```

I was looking at Microsoft's "Getting Started" for Winsock 2, and saw this:

```
struct addrinfo *result = NULL,
                    *ptr = NULL,
                    hints;

ZeroMemory( &hints, sizeof(hints) );
hints.ai_family = AF_UNSPEC;
hints.ai_socktype = SOCK_STREAM;
hints.ai_protocol = IPPROTO_TCP;
```

What kind of struct is this? I figure the name of the struct is `addrinfo`, but then what type are `*result`, `*ptr`, or `hints`?

Also, how is `hints` given a `.ai_family/socktype/protocol` when it never was coded previously?

Comment: Just a few lines above that piece of code, in the sentence "Declare an addrinfo object", is a link that reads "addrinfo". You didn't consider clicking it to see if it could lead to anything useful?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

`struct addrinfo` is a standard data structure to contain network address information. It is defined by e.g. POSIX, aka [SingleUnix](http://pubs.opengroup.org/onlinepubs/009695399/basedefs/netdb.h.html). You get it by including `netdb.h` or your OS' equivalent. Its fields are (at least):

```
int               ai_flags      Input flags. 
int               ai_family     Address family of socket. 
int               ai_socktype   Socket type. 
int               ai_protocol   Protocol of socket. 
socklen_t         ai_addrlen    Length of socket address. 
struct sockaddr  *ai_addr       Socket address of socket. 
char             *ai_canonname  Canonical name of service  location. 
struct addrinfo  *ai_next       Pointer to next in list.
```

`struct addrinfo *result = NULL, *ptr = NULL, hints;`

`result` and `ptr` are pointers to `struct addrinfo`. `hints` is a stack-allocated `struct addrinfo`.

The Windows Socket API is a pure C API hence it uses C conventions. Structure variables in C must be declared explictly with `struct`. You cannot leave off the `struct` as in C++. They are also not initialized, hence the `memset()`^W`ZeroMemory()`

Comment: This appears to be an appropriate answer to the user's question!

Answer (score 7):

It's a C-style way of declaring a variable as an instance of a struct. `addrinfo` is the struct that's defined elsewhere, and `result` is a pointer to an instance of one. [Here is the actual definition of addrinfo](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/windows/desktop/ms737530%28v=vs.85%29.aspx?f=255&MSPPError=-2147217396)

In modern C++, the following is equivalent:

```
addrinfo* result = NULL; // nullptr in C++11 and beyond
addrinfo* ptr = NULL; // nullptr in C++11 and beyond
addrinfo  hints;
```